# Foreign Key Constraint does not exist ERROR

Tags: sql-server, database, postgresql, foreign-keys, constraints

I keep getting this error in my psql database;

```
bikefacility=# ERROR:  syntax error at or near "c"
bikefacility-# LINE 1: c
bikefacility-#         ^
bikefacility-# bikefacility=# ALTER TABLE bicycle ADD CONSTRAINT fk_maintenance_contact_person FOREIGN KEY (maintenance_contact_person) REFERENCES maintenance(maintenance_contact_person);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ERROR"
LINE 1: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "c"
        ^
bikefacility=# ERROR:  column "maintenance_contact_person" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
bikefacility-# bikefacility=# ALTER TABLE bicycle ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rental_period FOREIGN KEY (rental_period) REFERENCES rental(rental_period);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ERROR"
LINE 1: ERROR:  column "maintenance_contact_person" referenced in fo...
        ^
bikefacility=# ERROR:  column "rental_period" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
bikefacility-# bikefacility=# ALTER TABLE bicycle ADD CONSTRAINT fk_terminal_id FOREIGN KEY (terminal_id) REFERENCES terminal(terminal_id);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ERROR"
LINE 1: ERROR:  column "rental_period" referenced in foreign key con...
        ^
bikefacility=# ERROR:  column "terminal_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist
```

This is my code. I've created the same style of foreign keys within the code as you can see here.

```
CREATE TABLE member (
  member_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  member_fname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  member_lname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  member_status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  member_address VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  member_email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE bicycle (
  bicycle_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  bicycle_brand VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  bicycle_model VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  bicycle_colour VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  bicycle_type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  bicycle_size VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  bicycle_availability VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL

);

ALTER TABLE bicycle ADD CONSTRAINT fk_bicycle_pickup_date FOREIGN KEY (bicycle_pickup_date) REFERENCES rental(bicycle_pickup_date) >MATCH FULL;
ALTER TABLE bicycle ADD CONSTRAINT fk_maintenance_contact_person FOREIGN KEY (maintenance_contact_person) REFERENCES maintenance(maintenance_contact_person);
ALTER TABLE bicycle ADD CONSTRAINT fk_terminal_id FOREIGN KEY (terminal_id) REFERENCES terminal(terminal_id);
ALTER TABLE bicycle ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rental_period FOREIGN KEY (rental_period) REFERENCES rental(rental_period);

CREATE TABLE sponsor (
  sponsor_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  sponsor_name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  sponsor_contact VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  sponsor_period DATE NOT NULL,
  sponsor_address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  sponsor_fee DECIMAL (6, 2) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE terminal (
  terminal_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  terminal_address VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  terminal_minstorage VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  terminal_maxstorage VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE rental (
  rental_no INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  rental_period DATE NOT NULL,
  bicycle_pickup_date DATE NOT NULL
);
```

It says that the columns don't exist but I know they do because they're right there! Can someone help me out, please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: SQL server or PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1):

The grammar of the the foreign keys are incorrect for postgresql.  For instance, `ALTER TABLE bicycle ADD CONSTRAINT fk_terminal_id FOREIGN KEY (terminal_id) REFERENCES terminal(terminal_id);` requires there to be a field in bicycles, named terminal_id as the former terminal_id in your query refers to bicycle table, which should reference terminal_id in the terminal table.

Here is a short tutorial of foreign keys.  https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-foreign-key/

Best regards,
Bjarni

Answer (score 0):

Your schema is quite messed up.

- There's no table `maintenance` yet you try to make a reference to it.
- The foreign table like `rental` must be created before you make a fk reference to it.
- You must have the named fields in the table where you make the reference from. There are no fields `bicycle_pickup_date`, `maintenance_contact_person`, `terminal_id` or `rental_period` in table `bicycle.`
- Your fk references in general sound odd. Do you really want that each bicycle could have only only one rental, ever? Maybe you meant that a rental references to a single bicycle?

Also, your naming convention is quite redundant. There's no need to repeat table name in each field name, that just adds unneeded clutter in your code.